Apollo Client is refetching a query after an add mutation but not a delete
I have a mutation that adds a todo to a list of todos.
mutation AddTodo($data: AddTodoInput!) {
              addTodoToList(data: $data) {
                id
                todos{
                  id
                }
              }
            }

I have another mutation that deletes a todo:
mutation DeleteTodo($data: DeleteTodoInput!) {
              deleteTodoFromList(data: $data) {
                id
                todos{
                  id
                }
              }
            }

This is the query for the list:
query List{
    id,
    todos {
       id
       name
    }
              
}

The delete properly deletes the todo and removes it from the list without refetching the list. But when I add an item, it causes a refetch. Since I'm returning the todos list, that's unexpected. What's the issue?

Because my AddTodo query was not requesting the "name" field back, the List query didn't have the name of the new todo and was forced to refetch the List query to get the name.
Adding the "name" field to the AddTodo mutation made it so the List query wasn't refetched.
Delete didn't cause a refetch because it was removing an item and List doesn't need more information about fields that don't exist.
